# How to iterate over a xml file by xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

suppose I have a xml file as below:

```
<root>
<element1>value1</element1>
<element2>value2</element2>
<element3>value3</element3>
</root>
```

I want to iterate over this xml file, and store the element name and value in a map. How to do that by xmlstarlet? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do it

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "/root[*]" -v . your.xml
```

Explanation:

```
sel -t
```

standard setup for select with output

```
-m "/root[*]"
```

This requires a match (-m) at the literal "root" of the document '/root' and for every direct node, in this case defined as an XPath wildcard (*), do something.
 (**FYI** - to get funky with xmlstarlet you have to use a little XPath - just make sure to always wrap in (). also handy when using '-i')

```
-v .
```

This is requesting the value of an element in the current path (-v) and the '.' is for the current element in the iteration. (since we don't know the name)

```
your.xml
```

file name. (yours, not mine)

Hope that helps you out.

-DG